# Could I open two EASessions in my iOS app to communicate with my external accessory?

Tags: ios, eaaccessory

Can I open **two EASessions** for communicating with external accessory? **One EASession** for control command, **the other EASession** for streaming data.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code here. As well as an explanation of what you're trying to do, and why what you have tried didn't work. Questions that can simply be answer with a "yes" or "no" aren't good questions, and I recommend reviewing the guides on how to improve your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @WannaFly please edit your question detail for ease reading, and your question will contains codes here.

Comment: @ChristianF, aircraft  Sorry to ask so bad question, I haven't implement code yet, and also we are applying for MFI. so, I want to make sure EAAccessory can support multiple sessions with one app or not.  We want to develop an app to communicate with external camera device, and try to control camera settings(like white-balance, explosion, and so on) in one session, and receive video stream using the other session. I don't know whether it is a good solution, or by using custom protocol using one session.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [reading the manual for EAAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/Connecting.html), as it clearly states:

> For a given accessory object, only one session at a time is allowed for a specific protocol.

So, yes: As long as the protocols are different, you can have multiple sessions. If they aren't, is there anything preventing you from using a second EAAccessory object..?

Comment: were this recommended way was helpful?? i also have to implement the same thing. Please reply.

Comment: how we will be able to play the video stream ?

Comment: how can we defferentiate the stream, since 
- (void)stream:(NSStream*)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent doesnot have a type to deffer the session object.